# sort a list of objects on attribute 'a', producing a list of 'c' attributes

Tags: python, sorting

```
class A:
     def __init__():
         self.a = 0
         self.b = 0
         self.c = 0

l = [object1 of A, object2 of A, object3 of A]

l = sorted(l, key=somefunc)
```

The list contains separate values for a, b, c for each instance. I will sort using a custom function which uses attribute a, but I want it to return a new list containing only the values of the attribute c(in sorted order of course).

Comment: Why not created a custom `sorted` of your own, which takes a `list` of instances and returns only the relevant attribute of each?

Comment: @SamChats: that's.. rather a bit of overkill. `sorted(o.c for o in l)` can do that without creating a new function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters :) yes it is, and I think the answer provided is a better way to go...

Comment: @MartijnPieters you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the answer. Can the attrgetter be used here?

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol: yes. `sorted(map(attrgetter('c'), l))` would do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieter I have edited the question. Please unmark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the values first, then sort.

```
objects_to_sort = [x.c for x in l]
objects_to_sort.sort()
```

Note that since your list now contains just the attributes, there is no need for a key function.

Comment: Why not use `sorted()` and a generator expression?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to take two steps, sorting first, then extracting the attribute of your choice:

```
[o.c for o in sorted(l, key=somefunc)]
```